# Properties generated at runtime (PropertyGrid.SelectedObject)

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, propertygrid

Ok, this is a tough one.

**Introduction:** My idea is to attach an instanciated QueryBuilder class which I wrote, to a PropertyGrid. The QueryBuilder class now contains a couple of fields, which are hardcoded like in the example below. Thus allowing a user to specify, which fields should be used in a query in what way (sorted, grouped, and so on). After the user having specified all the settings to these properties (by code or via the PropertyGrid GUI), the QueryBuilder is able to produce a query. Everything is working fine like that. Pseudo code:

```
class QueryBuilder {
  public QBField name {get; set;}
  public QBField prename {get; set;}
  public QBField zip {get; set;}
  // ...

  public void QueryBuilder() {
    name = new QBField();
    prename = new QBField();
    // ...
  }

  public getQuery() {
    // logic to build the query
  }
}

class QBField {
  public bool shown {get; set;}
  public bool sortby {get; set;}
  public bool groupby {get; set;}
}
```

**Challenge:** Now instead of hardcoding each field as public properties in the QueryBuilder class, I was wondering how I could use i.e. a `List<string>` containing all my fields to "populate" my instanciated QueryBuilder with these properties.

So this leads to three questions:

1. Could this be accomplished by somehow overriding GetProperties() of the Type of the QueryBuilder class, and if yes, how is it best done?
2. How can I then iterate through all of these at runtime generated QBField properties and instanciate them? Idea: PropertyDescriptors and Activators?
3. How can I iterate through all of these properties to read the values of each QBField object? The problem I ran in was, that when reading the Properties of QBField with reflection and trying getValue(obj, null), of course the first parameter needed is an object, which I do not know since I have lots of these QBField objects. Perhaps putting all my QBFields into a `List<QBField>` and iterating through it? Would that work in this example?

I'm just a bit lost but I feel that I'm very close to the solution. Therefore any help or just pointers in the right direction are most greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PropertyGrid` can be influenced via `TypeConverter`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and/or `TypeDescriptionProvider`. Of these, `TypeConverter` is the simplest, by overriding `GetProperties` (and mark it as supported).

In any event, you will also need to write a `PropertyDescriptor` implementation that knows how to take a field and an object, and get/set the value, i.e.

```
public override void SetValue(object component, object value) {
    ((YourType)component)[fieldNameSetInConstructor] = value;
}
```

---

Here's a *basic* property bag that exposes everything as `string`; obviously as you extend this (different property types, change-notification, etc) it gets more complex very quickly. Note also that this `TypeConverter` approach only works for `PropertyGrid`; for `DataGridView` etc you'll need either `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`. For collections you'll need `ITypedList`. And there are about 20 other interfaces around the edges for specific scenarios. But you get the point ;p The key thing is that our `PropertyDescriptor` acts as the translation between your *actual* model (the dictionary in my case), and the model you expose to `TypeDescriptor` (the fake properties per key).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var bag = new BasicPropertyBag { Properties = {
            new MetaProp("Name", typeof(string)),
            new MetaProp("Description", typeof(string)),
            new MetaProp("DateOfBirth", typeof(DateTime)
                , new CategoryAttribute("Personal"), new DisplayNameAttribute("Date Of Birth"))
        } };
        bag["Name"] = "foo";
        bag["DateOfBirth"] = DateTime.Today;
        Application.Run(new Form { Controls = { new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SelectedObject = bag } } });
    }
}

public class MetaProp
{
    public MetaProp(string name, Type type, params Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        if (attributes != null)
        {
            Attributes = new Attribute[attributes.Length];
            attributes.CopyTo(Attributes, 0);
        }
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Type Type { get; private set; }
    public Attribute[] Attributes { get; private set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(BasicPropertyBagConverter))]
class BasicPropertyBag
{

    private readonly List<MetaProp> properties = new List<MetaProp>();
    public List<MetaProp> Properties { get { return properties; } }
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { object value; return values.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : null; }
        set { if (value == null) values.Remove(key); else values[key] = value; }
    }

    class BasicPropertyBagConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor[] metaProps = (from prop in ((BasicPropertyBag)value).Properties
                                              select new PropertyBagDescriptor(prop.Name, prop.Type, prop.Attributes)).ToArray();
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(metaProps);
        }
    }
    class PropertyBagDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private readonly Type type;
        public PropertyBagDescriptor(string name, Type type, Attribute[] attributes)
            : base(name, attributes) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public override Type PropertyType { get { return type; } }
        public override object GetValue(object component) { return ((BasicPropertyBag)component)[Name]; }
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { ((BasicPropertyBag)component)[Name] = (string)value; }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return GetValue(component) != null; }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return true; }
        public override void ResetValue(object component) { SetValue(component, null); }
        public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
        public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(BasicPropertyBag); } }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for pointing me to the right direction. Got the things so far working but have no idea how to create new properties. Have implemented GetProperties and am able to filter properties there. But how to add properties (i.e. from my List<string>? Any idea?

Comment: @Gregor - what is the `string` in that case? I've written quite a few of these dynamic/property-bag models, and the first thing to uderstand is the exact scenario. I'll do a quick simple mockup, though...

Comment: @Gregor - note I have a number of other posts on SO and elsewhere discussing more complex corners of this. It is not a trivial area, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Marc - Thank you very much! This really helped me a lot, from this point on, I should be able to finish the scenario by using a List of objects instead of strings as properties. These objects have static properties, so this should be quite similar to your example.

Comment: @Gregor - indeed you should be able to *combine* the `PropertyDescritor` arrays to get a mix of reflective and dynamic properties.

Comment: Okay that works all marvelous, have now my objects as properties all loading dynamically and expandable. Just juggling a bit around with setting categories dynamically - ie not in PropertyBagDescriptor but directly in the Converter or (but would be much more complex) when adding a new object from the main routine (ie string in your example)... any chance for a last pointer?

Comment: @Gregor isn't Category one of the overrides?

Comment: @Marc yes that's true. But if I understood correctly, this ist just the main descriptor for all of my properties. I would like to set categories depending on certain content of the objects. I thought about making a descriptor for each category and assigning it then dynamically - but am not sure, if that's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Gregor - updated to illustrate; you can of course use any logic you need to set the category per-instance, etc

Comment: @Marc With your help I'm now able to set everything as dynamic as it could ever be :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Marc, have you ever had the issue, where you were updating a property (an object) in the propertygrid by gui, and the string representation of the object in the PG not being updated? Here it updates only when i click in the property or when I declare the properties by [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]. With RefreshProperties, although the node collapses everytime I change something in the gui...

Comment: @Gregor - I've seen that on *related* properties i.e. I update `A` in the UI, which (via the setter) updates `B` - in the UI `A` is up to date but `B` is stale. IIRC `RefreshProperties` is the way to look at this, but you could *try* using the change events on the `PropertyDescriptor` (but do a simple test first, as I can't remember if this is respected by PG)

Comment: @Marc Thx, will try this. The RefreshProperties unfortunately resets the expanded/collapsed states of my expandable objects. I think I will open a new question, certainly someone encountered something similar (browsing the web approves this). Thx anyway for all your help! If you tell me your postal address, I'll send you a postcard from switzerland :)