# Providing values to enum properties generated at runtime for propertygrid

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, propertygrid

I needed to add enum properties at runtime to be displayed inside the proertygrid, this lead me to this page

[Properties generated at runtime (PropertyGrid.SelectedObject)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091888/properties-generated-at-runtime-propertygrid-selectedobject)

which did the job as I wanted. I tested this with a static enum, but I also need to provide user defined values to the enum at runtime. I do understand that I need to change the

```
 public override StandardValuesCollection
             GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
```

method, but the problem is that the context.instance property shows all the properties inside the bag described in the mentioned stackoverflow page. So if I have 5 properties the instance property will have an array of 5 properties; how can I find out which one is the one I should mess with? Is there any other way to provide the values to the enum besides populating it inside the GetStandardValues() method?

cheers,
ES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ITypeDescriptorContext object has a PropertyDescriptor.Name property

```
context.PropertyDescriptor.Name
```

this will show the element.

-ES