# ExpandableObjectConverter for a "Black box" dll class in order to show properties in the propertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I want to create an instance of a type defined in a "Black Box" DLL, and then show the properties using `PropertiesGrid`

The type has internal complex types in it, that i want them to be viewed in an expendable item.
But I can't decorate the internal types with `[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`

since the DLL is a "BlackBox"

What can I do?

Comment: My idea is to create a class containing property bindings between itself and the "black box" class (and its nested classes), intended to act as datasource to the `PropertyGrid`.  Maybe these answers will point you to the right direction: [answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4091938), [answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4591163)

Comment: How do I bind properties?